# ReportPanic on OS X Yosemite 10.10.2

Tags: macos, crash

I run OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 on a first generation 27" iMac.
Over night the computer apparently crashed.

All applications I had open had gotten all jumbled in the restart so I pressed the `F3` to see every thing and saw the following pop-up message:

[image]

I've seen these kind of messages before, but I had never seen them labeled as "ReportPanic".

Can someone explain what this is and what it means?  The label gives me pause.  Is this a real OS X message or a possible hack?

Comment: just click on the "Report" and you will see if it is real or not. If you wish us to help you publish some 50 lines here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ReportPanic is the name of the application that saves your data and handles crashing. It is a normal OS X application.

Comment: That sets my mind at ease.  Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: @Jagra Just to confirm, you were in Mission Control when you took that picture, right?

Comment: Yes, in Mission Control